# Rails - Calling JS function in app/javascript from a js.erb in app/views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

Beginner with Rails (v5.2.1), I try to incorporate some javascript.

I have a function `extendCard` in *app/javascript/packs* that put an event listener on all my elements with the class "card". I exported this function and imported it in *app/javascript/packs/application.js*. This function works when I call it from *application.js*.

To make it easy, let's say this function is :

```
function extendCard() {
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("click works");
    });
  }
}

export { extendCard };
```

And in *application.js*:

```
import { extendCard } from './extend';
extendCard();
```

In *views/layouts/application.html.erb* I put :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Sometimes, I need to refresh the cards displayed but want to do it with ajax. I put a `remote: true` on the button that refresh the cards displayed (with filters) and I render new cards with a *js.erb* file stored in *app/views/cards*. The refresh works fine.

Now, I need to add again the event listener on those new cards. I would like to call my function `extendCard` but I don't know how to reach it. When I call it, i got :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: extendCard is not defined

The only thing I can do is to rewrite my function inside the *js.erb* (but actually I have a lot of them) and it's not very DRY.

Note that I have the *webpacker gem*. I don't understand it very much but I think it's related.

So, my question: how can I access easily to the functions imported in *app/javascript/packs/application.js*? I would like to make it in Vanilla JS if it's possible.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the same issue

Comment: I had a similar issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66244317/10984558) answer might be helpful.