# Is it possible to import JS function into a js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to import a JS function to be used in a `js.erb` file?

For example:

```
// hello_world.js
const helloWorld = () => console.log('hello world');
export default helloWorld;
```

And:

```
// our_file.js.erb
import helloWorld from 'path/to/hello_world.js';

helloWorld();
```

I've had a pop at it and can't get it firing, so presume the answer is no - will happily accept a one word answer if this is indeed the case.

If not, how does one go about getting this working? Thanks in advance for all help / constructive criticism / mockery.

---

**Edit**

I'm not sure the suggested duplicate *is* a duplicate of this - I'm specifically looking to import a function, not load an entire script into the DOM. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to load a Javascript file to rails html erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533969/how-to-load-a-javascript-file-to-rails-html-erb)

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533969/how-to-load-a-javascript-file-to-rails-html-erb
Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: Thanks @AnujKhandelwal - I'm not sure that's what I'm after though. I'm looking to just import a single function, rather than load an entire file into the DOM.

Comment: Oh, my apologies for marking this as a possible duplicate. Is there a way I can undo that?

Comment: Not a problem @AnujKhandelwal - appreciate any attempt to help out :) Believe you can withdraw a vote through either the close or flag button under the question.

Answer (score 1):

By making the function available on the window you can call it inside your view or `js.erb` file.

```
// hello_world.js
const helloWorld = () => console.log('hello world');

window.helloWorld = helloWorld;
```

```
// our_file.js.erb
helloWorld();
```

I'm not sure if this is best practice but it's a workaround.